# Call a function only if it hasn't been called / run a function only once

Tags: javascript

I have a function `animate_images` running on some of my website's pages that performs a certain animation.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when a user navigates to the same page again, the function is called for the second time, in addition to its already running instance.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
if ! (animate_images) {
  animate_images();
}
```

Essentially, I want to make sure that `animate_images` never runs more than once, no matter how many times it is actually called.

Comment: you could try using a global boolean

Comment: Could you pleae elaborate, @Accipheran? I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: There is only ever one thread running in Javascript, so the other `animate_images` cannot be running for that if statement to execute. There is most likely a timeout in the event queue waiting for your thread to finish so that it can execute again.

Comment: How is the function still running when user loads another page or reloads the same one?

Comment: The problem is, it does, @Paulpro.

Comment: Actually, all my pages are AJAX-loaded, @Dogbert.

Comment: Is this a public page we can visit to see the problem/error?

Comment: You could add to animate_images an `is_running` property, set it `true` at the start of the `animate_images()` function and then set to to `false` whenever the interval / timeout is cleared / the animation is stopped.

Comment: I like Paulpro's idea, but whatever you do, please do not use a global boolean. Once you start down that road you'll have your entire app running on global state sooner than you know it.

Comment: Paulpro's idea is IMO the correct way to do this. At the start of the function add `if(!this.is_running) { ... launch animation ...; this.is_running = true; }`

Comment: Could it be declared with the name of the function instead of `this`, like `animate_images.is_running` @taz?

Comment: Yes, if you know that the function will never be instantiated more than once (not called with `new`), then you can use a "static" property of your function object, as in `animate_images.is_running`. I can't remember offhand - that might technically make `animate_images.is_running` a global (or in the same scope as `is_running`), as opposed to actually being a property of `is_running`, but the effect should be the same. If you were instantiating `animate_images` with `new`, then you would use `this`. IIRC in Javascript `this` is scoped to the "closest" function instance.

Comment: Thank you, @taz, I'm going to try that.

Comment: @KeithRules Clarification: even if your function _is_ instantiated with `new`, using a static property as mentioned above technically still works (won't cause a parsing or Javascript error), but distinct instances of `animate_image` will interfere with each other because they all reference the same static variable. Using `this` will not do what you need if `animate_images` is _not_ instantiated with `new` (because `this` will not refer to `animate_images`). It sounds like you're not using `new` so the static solution should achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you @taz. The solution, offered by you and Paulpro is the one I used, and it worked. I wish either you or Paulpro wrote it as an actual answer, so I could mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a static property of your function object, as in a boolean `animate_images.isRunning`. At the start of `animate_images`, encapsulate the animation initialization with something like

```
animate_images() {
    // on first load, animate_images.isRunning is undefined,
    //     so (!animate_images.isRunning) returns true.
    if(!animate_images.isRunning) { 
        /* launch animation */;
        // define animate_images.isRunning and assign true
        animate_images.isRunning = true;
    } else { 
        /* animation already initialized */ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `once` function from underscore.js - [linked here](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-66).

Essentially, you wrap the function in another one that has a flag variable inside it. Call the function if the flag is unset and set the flag when you call it.

```
_.once = function(func) {
  var ran = false, memo;
  return function() {
    if (ran) return memo;
    ran = true;
    memo = func.apply(this, arguments);
    func = null;
    return memo;
};
```

};

If you don't want to add underscore to your website (I think that's the first thing you should do when starting any website, but I digress), do this:

```
runOnlyOnce = function(func) {...} // As defined above

animate_images = runOnlyOnce(animate_images);
```

or

```
animate_images = runOnlyOnce(function(){
    alert('Animate all the things!');
});
```

The function itself has no dependencies on the rest of underscore.

Comment: Thank you, @Sudhir – is there a way to do that without adding an additional JS library to my already library- heavy website?

Comment: Yes, just rewrite this function and give it a name you like

Comment: Could you please add the placeholder for my function inside the one you posted, @SudhirJonathan? I'm pretty new to JavaScript and even that is a bit of a challenge. Should it be after the `return memo`?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood you and all I need to wrap the function is to place it inside the parentheses, when `runOnlyOnce` function is called, as you showed?

Comment: Yes, you can also do this: `animate_images = runOnlyOnce(function(){alert('Images Animated');});`

Comment: Somehow not working. Tried it the way you described, it only disables the animation completely. Would you find a few minutes for a chat, @SudhirJonathan ?

Comment: @SudhirJonathan In case you didn't already know (and would rather not publicly give out your email address in the future), Stack Overflow has chat (link at the top) available to all users with [at least 20 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat).

Comment: I didn't know that, actually. Used it once before, but didn't know how to start a conversation with this user in particular. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You could override your function with an empty function once it has been executed:

```
function a(){
    console.log("hello");
    a = function(){};
}

a();  //"hello"
a();  //>>nothing happens<<
```

Actually this will just override the reference `a` to your function. So this only works if you don't reference to the same function multiple times. If you do something like this:

```
function a(){
    console.log("hello");
    a = function(){};
}

var obj { b:a };

a();  //"hello"
a();  //>>nothing happens<<
obj.b(); //"hello"
```

this method will fail.