# Run the function only once if its been called 50 times in 1 second

Tags: javascript, function, repeat

This is the function and what is does, is playing a sound when new order is coming. So there be 50 orders coming all at once, now it play the sound 50 times, where only 1 time is enough. Any idea how I can achieve this?

```
function playSound() {
    var audio = new Audio('/audio/short_notification.mp3');
    audio.play()
}
```

Found some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174308/call-a-function-only-if-it-hasnt-been-called-run-a-function-only-once) but they did not provide a much of help on this.

Comment: What you are looking for is called debounce or dethrottle

Comment: If the orders come _"all at once"_ why are there then sounds for each of them? Who ever imports those orders should trigger that sound once for the import instead of once for every order.

Comment: Can you add the code, where the method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout function to reset  variable that controls the audio play.

```
let isPlaying = true;
const silentTimeOutCounter = 1000;

function playSound() {
    if(isPlaying){
      var audio = new Audio('/audio/short_notification.mp3');
      audio.play();
      isPlaying = false;
      setTimeout(() => {isPlaying = true;} ,silentTimeOutCounter);
    }
}

playSound();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `timer` and check if the function was called in the last second.

```js
let timer = 0;

function playSound() {
    if (Date.now() - timer < 1000) return;
    timer = Date.now();
    var audio = new Audio('/audio/short_notification.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable var to check if it is played once.

```
var isPlayedOnce = false;

function playSound() {
    if(!isPlayedOnce){
         var audio = new Audio('/audio/short_notification.mp3');
         audio.play();
         isPlayedOnce = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works in the first operation, but when later new order comes the value is always true unless we reload the browser to re-initialize the flag as false.

Comment: Then, you can update this isPlayedOnce to true when you get the new order but this will work only when you are able distinguish between the new order and old order. If this is not your case then you can wait for some time and update the isPlayedOnce to true using the setTimeout or by using any variable(store previous time on it.)